# IIS Administration PowerShell Cmdlets on Windows 2008 R1

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, powershell

I am trying to use IIS Administration PowerShell Cmdlets on top of Windows 2008 R1. According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) you need to load these Cmdlets. However the options to load the cmdlets does not exist in Windows 2008 R1, how do I load these or what do I need to do?

Comment: Windows 2008 R1 requires you to install a snap-in to get WebAdministration.  Windows 2008 R2 has WebAdministration built in as a module. And just to make life interesting snap-ins and modules are loaded with different commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the snapin containing the cmdlets. (A snapin is the PSH1, supported in V2, means of implementing cmdlets. In V2 modules are a better, more flexible, approach.)

There are some details here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/429/installing-the-iis-70-powershell-snap-in/ which details the shortcut installed which is pre-configured with the snapin loaded.

Comment: Yup, this did it. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

The article you mentioned said "By default, Windows PowerShell modules and snap-ins are not loaded in Windows PowerShell. To start Windows PowerShell so that all the Windows PowerShell modules and snap-ins are loaded automatically, right-click the Windows PowerShell icon in the taskbar, and then click Import all modules. ". Did you try this method to load the IIS module?

Comment: You can do that on Windows 2008 R2, but there is no such option on Windows 2008 R1. That's the problem!